# Autocomplete input text field with Javascript based on a PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, autocomplete

I wrote this code to do autocomplete from a PHP array but it is not working, can anybody help?

PHP array:

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
```

My form:

```
<form id="frm" method="post">
    <input id="cartag" type="text" name="car">
</form>
```

JS script:

```
$(function() {
var availableTags = [ <?php echo implode(',', $cars); ?>];
    $( "#cartag" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
    });
});
```

Comment: tell us what does your JS look like after the PHP is executed.

Comment: sorry but i am beginner, how can i tell you what does it look like after executing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use a PHP array in jQuery, you have to use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

like this:

```
var availableTags =  <?php echo json_encode($cars); ?>;
```

Working demo:

```
<?php

$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");

?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form id="frm" method="post">
<input id="cartag" type="text" name="car">
</form>
<script>

$(function() {
var availableTags =  <?php echo json_encode($cars); ?>;
    $( "#cartag" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote each string in the array (otherwise they'll be treated as variables, which are undefined):

```
var availableTags = [ <?php echo '"' . implode('","', $cars) . '"'; ?> ];
```

Comment: are you including jquery ui?

Comment: yes i do <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: json strings should not be manually crafted -- this would not be a reliable technique if the values themselves might contain double quotes.

Answer (score -1):

**You need jquery ui.**
Here is a simplified version, without considering PHP;
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a92y4458/)

```
var lst = ["Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"];
$( "#cartag" ).autocomplete({
    source: lst
    });
```

to parse your array correctly from PHP to js:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
<?php
$php_array = array('abc','def','ghi');
$js_array = json_encode($php_array);
echo "var javascript_array = ". $js_array . ";\n";
?>
</script>
```

Comment: i need to put php array into java array automatically, what do you suggest to do with that?

Comment: This doesn't say anything about how to pass the array from the php/html to the js code.